# MySQL - PDO - Allow if POSTS are NULL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If i fill every input in the form, the data will go successfully into the database, but when i don't fill the input telephone, the data will not go to the database and will give a error :

**`error sqlstate 23000 integrity constraint violation 1048 column 'telephone' cannot be null`**

So that means, if the field telephone is empty, and i will click submit the data will not go into the database.

So my question is: How can i allow that if the textinput 'telephone' is not filled, the data will still go into the database?

This is the .php

```
<?php


include("dbconfig.php");

if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{

try {


    $date= date('d.m.y');
    $tijd= date("H:i A");
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 


    $mhbt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (name, email, telephone, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $mhbt->bindParam(1, $_POST["name"]);
    $mhbt->bindParam(2, $_POST["email"]);
    $mhbt->bindParam(3, $_POST["telephone"]);
    $mhbt->bindParam(4, $_POST["city"]);


    $mhbt->bindParam(5, $date);
    $mhbt->bindParam(6, $tijd);
    $mhbt->bindParam(7, $ip);

    $mhbt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

}



?>
```

Comment: change in table. Change the default value  of `telephone field` to `null`.  so that if no value is assigned then automatically null will be added to `telephone` field. try and tell what happen. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when ever you are creating columns with `not null` attribute. You need to pass value always when you want to save the data to that table.

Change in table. Change the default value of `telephone field to null`. so that if no value is assigned then automatically `null` will be added to `telephone field`.

Just do a query like this:- `ALTER TABLE orders MODIFY COLUMN telephone VARCHAR(15) NULL`

Note:- It will be more good to do at db  level. it will give relaxation from future problems.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with the telephone being `null`, just change the schema to allow it:

```
ALTER TABLE orders MODIFY COLUMN telephone VARCHAR(15) NULL
```

If you aren't, modify the table to have some default value:

```
ALTER TABLE orders MODIFY COLUMN telephone VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '000-0-0000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 2 possibilities to your problem:

**1- You change the database structure**

a) by allowing NULL values

```
ALTER TABLE orders MODIFY COLUMN telephone VARCHAR(50) NULL;
```

b) by setting a default value (like an empty string)

```
ALTER TABLE orders MODIFY COLUMN telephone VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

**2- Write the empty phone number as an empty string**

```
$mhbt->bindParam(3, (isset($_POST["telephone"]) ? $_POST["telephone"] : ''));
```

If you can edit the database structure, I think you should pick option 1.  If you have to control on the database structure and must send an empty phone number, use option 2.